# jquery-ui multi-select widget labels and checkboxes selecting the wrong field

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using 2 instances of a multi-select field on a single page.
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

The problem that I am running into is when I select a label (not a checkbox) of the first instance of a multi-select field, it is checking the box for the 2nd instance of the multi-select field.

The reason is that the labels' class names are the same in both instances. This behavior would be okay but clicking the label on the first field doesn't click on it's respective checkbox.

I've set the class of both instances with different class names already using the new classes option in v1.5 but this does not change the class names of the labels.

Has anyone else run into this issue? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry - I was using the select_tag in rails and just realized that the labels for the multi-select comes from the name and ID of the text-field and not the class.  Changing the name and ID of the text fields to be different solved my problem.